# Shape along bezier curve with multiple materials

Tags: materials, bezier-curves

I have a shape consisting of multiple shapes (one object total with three circles in it).

[image]

I set this one shape/object as the geometry for a bezier curve to extrude it along the curve.

Now I would like to apply different materials to different parts of the extruded bezier curve.

Example:

[image]

Because I want to keep the flexibility of editing the curve and the original shape (three circles) converting everything to a mesh is not an option for me.

Is this possible to do in Blender? Having multiple materials and still keeping the bezier curve to be able to change the shape of the curve (and resulting mesh) later on?

Comment: Either separate the bevel object into three separate circles, or use an Array+Curve modifier instead

Comment: As far as I know I need three curves to bevel along if I have three seperate circles as bevel objects. I can't get the Array+Curve modifier to work for this scenario. Can you maybe share a working example?